# DNS progagation taking longer than expected?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I recently created a website and switched my DNS over to CloudFlare to take advantage of their firewall and caching. So it's been about 15 hours since I have done this, and my website has been available off and on, I see people on it using Google Analytics Real Time while I can't access it. Is this normal? This is really my first time doing this. And why did it delete my previous records which worked perfectly fine if it didn't update them yet? Does it usually do that.

Sorry for my lack of experience, however I am very concerned. Did I set it up correctly?

Also if this is the wrong section, please tell me!

Comment: Can take up to 24 hours or longer. You could contact Cloud Flare and see if they have any issues or news about the time their servers usually take to update. Especially if they are overseas. You could also run some trace routes to see if things are working better, try by IP and name.

Comment: Double check, if you haven't already, to make certain there are no locks preventing domain transfer.

Comment: There's no such thing as "DNS propagation".

Comment: Give us the domain name. Last few times I've seen this the users had two sets of nameservers configured in the domain's WHOIS. Usually trivially solvable with the real domain, impossible without.

Answer (score 1):

If your website has been available off and on after your changes, then yes, something is wrong.

Switching one good DNS to another good DNS does not result in any downtime at all.

You can use `dig` or a number of free online tools to analyze your DNS setup (googling for `analyze DNS setup online` returned five different tools as the first five results, the sixth result was a list of fourteen different tools).

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS nameservers, eg. using google's one, 8.8.8.8.

Assuming a linux console:

```
host -t NS $YOURDOMAIN 8.8.8.8
```

So you get the authoritative nameservers for you'r domain

Do the same with other open DNS servers (OpenDNS, web sites, as @Law29 suggested)
If the replies you get match your new DNS servers you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

It can take up to 48 hours for a domain to propagate entirely, but usually not more than 24 hours.

I always use this site to check if it's fully propagated or not: https://www.whatsmydns.net/